# Git merge conflict Tabbing in BASE

Tags: git-merge, meld, kdiff3, tabbing

I try to merge `branch A` to `branch B`. Both in `A` and `B` had inconsistent tabbing previously due to team work, but we fixed and the current version on `A` and `B` has the same tabbing. Now, when I try to merge the two branches I have merge conflicts (not due to the tabbing). When I try to solve the conflicts with **meld** (also tried with kdiff3, same thing) as `mergetool`, the `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` is with the same tabbing but the `BASE` is with the old tabbing as shown in the picture:
[image: melde tabbing diff in BASE to LOCAL and REMOTE]

Why does this happen?
It is hard to go through the tabbing fixes and also look for the conflicts during mrege. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the image shows the old tabbing in your `BASE` comes from the **first common ancestor** of the modified file in `branch A` and `branch B`. Then everything is going as expected.

You can try to add a hunk from any side (`LOCAL` or `REMOTE`) over the hunk with the old tabbing in `BASE`, since it is an outdated hunk. It should clarify the conflicts resolution.

Can you provide the full image or the `BASE`, `REMOTE` and `LOCAL` files from the conflict in something like a [gist](http://gist.github.com/)?

*this answer should be a comment, but i don't have reputation enough*

Comment: The attached image shows from left to right: `LOCAL` -> `BASE` -> `REMOTE`

Comment: If I got it right, the old tabbing is coming from `BASE` because it comes from the first common ancestor commit of the conflict. Try to add a hunk of any side (`LOCAL` or `REMOTE`) over the hunk with the tabbing in `BASE` since it is an outdated hunk. It should clarify the conflicts resolution.

Comment: @Elod I edited the answer after your comment, hope I was able to explain better